# SQL obtain first the id selected on a while, then the others from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to put first selected item in a list, and then the rest in order by id.

My table:

```
id:1 car: fiat
id:2 car:ford
id:3 car:vw
id:4 car:toyota
```

the problem in .com/index.php?car=fiat

```
$car = $_GET['car'];
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"select * from products order by (case id when 999 then 0 else 1 end), car asc");
```

and the body

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results )){
echo '
    <div id="'.$row["car"].'"></div>
';
}
```

In example:
if I get the value 3:
ID
3
1
2
4
5

if I get the value 4:
ID
4
1
2
3
5

I dont know where to put the variable $car to work properly.
Thanks and i apoligize for my english.

Comment: Can you show how the sample table should be ordered? Is it `2, 3, 4, 1`?

Comment: YES, thanks. I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ID is numeric and will always be >0, this will work (I've kept the parentheses from your original query; note they're optional):

```
select *
from products
order by (case id when 3 then 0 else id end), car asc
```

If the ID can have negative values then something like this would be safer:

```
select *
from products
order by (case id when 3 then 0 else 1 end), id, car asc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i used your first solution